# Как из параметров url выделить еще один url?

Tags: python

Есть url:

```
a = 'vk.com/share.php?url=ystav.net/article/o-sozdanii-vakciny&amp'
```

Здесь в параметрах содержится еще одна ссылка, как ее можно достать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну предполагаю что вот так:

```
url = a.split('?url=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Для разбора ссылок есть стандартная библиотека [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse).

```
import urllib.parse
url = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(a).query)["url"][0]
```